# Is this a compiler glitch?

Tags: java, methods, annotations

How is it a method can be written to accept an annotation type, yet there is no way to actually have an annotation type with which to pass it?

```
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Inherited
public @interface Sharpenable {}


@Sharpenable
public class Pencil {}


public void sharpen(Sharpenable sharpenable){
       System.out.println("sharpening a " + sharpenable.getClass().getSimpleName());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have instances of annotations. For your example it would be

```
 Sharpenable s = Pencil.class.getAnnotation(Sharpenable.class);
```

However, Annotations is an entity used in reflection code. For your example it does not make  more sense to have it created like this. `Sharpenable` should be an interface implemented by different other classes that can be sharpened. If you want to keep the style of annotating them your code would probably look something like this:

```
 public void sharpen(Object sharpenable){
     if (sharpenable.getClass.getAnnotation(Sharpenable.class) != null)
         System.out.println("sharpening a " + sharpenable.getClass().getSimpleName());
     else
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not a sharpenable.");
 }
```

Comment: Thanks Stephan.  Sounds to me like they should have named annotations @hinterface, as they are only hints that can be discovered by asking a type if it happens to be decorated with an annotation.